# Prisma Jest tests return undefined

Tags: jestjs, prisma

I'm transitioning from TypeORM to Prisma. All of my until test Prisma functions are returning `undefined`. I'm using dependency injection from https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/testing/unit-testing

```
      const mockCtx2 = createMockContext()
      const ctx2 = mockCtx2 as unknown as Context
      console.log("createDummyUser")
      console.log(ctx2)
      console.log(ctx2.prisma)
      console.log(ctx2.prisma.users)
```

returns

```
  console.log
    { prisma: { _isMockObject: true } }

      at test/userService.test.ts:889:15

  console.log
    { _isMockObject: true }

      at test/userService.test.ts:890:15

  console.log
    [Function: mockConstructor] {
      _isMockFunction: true,
      getMockImplementation: [Function (anonymous)],
      mock: [Getter/Setter],
      mockClear: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockReset: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockRestore: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockReturnValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockResolvedValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockRejectedValueOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockReturnValue: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockResolvedValue: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockRejectedValue: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockImplementationOnce: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockImplementation: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockReturnThis: [Function (anonymous)],
      mockName: [Function (anonymous)],
      getMockName: [Function (anonymous)],
      calledWith: [Function (anonymous)],
      _isMockObject: true
    }
```

All of my requests return `undefined`

```
const allUsers1 = await ctx2.prisma.users.findMany()
      console.log(allUsers1)
```

**UPDATE**

```
import prisma from '../client'

const u = await prisma.users.findMany()
console.log("****")
console.log(u)
```

client.ts

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

const prisma = new PrismaClient()
export default prisma
```

Comment: Is your repository public? there are a lot of moving parts so it's difficult to debug what could be going wrong without looking at the setup.

Comment: @NurulSundarani no, it's not public. I'll make a sample project and see if I can isolate it

Comment: Sure, that would be helpful